# How to customize Jackson JSON serialization based on request parameter in Spring MVC

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson

I am working on a project and we want to pass down [custom ContextAttributes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/ContextAttributes.html) to the [Jackson `ObjectMapper#writer()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writer(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.ContextAttributes)) method.

Basically I am imagining some kind of global piece of code that sits between the controllers and serialization. It should look at the HttpServletRequest, get a parameter and then hook into the serialization.

Writing a custom HttpMessageConverter doesn't seem to be enough because it does not have access to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Request this way

```
RequestAttributes ra = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (ra instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)ra).getRequest();
}
```

Or you can add a Filter and store Request in a ThreadLocal storage and  acccess from your custom HttpMessageConverter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter and apply that for all urls and implement the logic in the filter. The filter has access to request object

```js
public class FilterName extends GenericFilterBean {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
    FilterChain chain) {
    //TODP
  }
}
```

and add this to the security xml